# php ubuntu open terminal

Tags: php, ubuntu

I want to open new terminal window by PHP on my ubuntu 18.04. I have read a lot but nothing works for me.

Like:

```
shell_exec('php measurePerformance.php 47 844 email@yahoo.com > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');

exec("nohup /usr/bin/php -f sleep.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

Above doesn't work. And I don't want to redirect output to file, I need open terminal window without waiting for finish, when user open some page.
Because in CLI PHP I can do it simply:

```
shell_exec("gnome-terminal -e 'php /var/www/run.php'");
```

But on windows it works by this way:

$cmd = "start php script.php";
pclose(popen($cmd, "r"));

I have tried on Ubuntu:

```
$script = "php $commandPath  $params";
pclose(popen($script, 'r'));
```

But seems apache stacks and page loading and loading, I need restart apache2.

Maybe I can realize it via extra .sh file? And firstly run this sh file and it will start new terminal window ? In new terminal I need  to execute another php scipt, using my PHP CLI.

Comment: you can't. at least not how you have explained it. all three lines of code  above do quite different things. what exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score -1):

```
$script = "php $commandPath  $params";
pclose(popen($script, 'r'));
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21228419)